# OO design approach - Reference based approach or ID based approach

Tags: entity-framework, oop, ooad

I have been doing some OO design of late. I also use EF 4.1 as the ORM. Now when i design my classes and their associations, I can think for two approaches. One is for example a Teacher teaches a subject. So Teacher class can have either a reference of the subject object as a property(reference based approach), or it can have SubjectId as a property(ID based approach). I am not sure which approach should be taken and why? I believe ID based approach is more of a relational data approach and reference based approach is true OO approach. But i am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JPA choose reference based approach with lazy fetching.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please help me with a reason for that. So why not ID based approach?

Comment: What purpose of Id approach? In general, your teacher teaches subject (as object) not id. It better represents OOP aproach. Even if you hold subject id, you need additional processing manually (get this id, pull entry with id and so on). In object case with lazy fetching all these things performs manually. One problem with this can appear with serialization and using remote lazy fetching.